# Get value from dynamic field with Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamic

I've a list of object. I want get all values in a field I've dynamically.
I explain more. I read all property of my dynamic object. When I found an image field, i want obtain all images in my list of object.

```
  For Each col In Ret.StructTbl.LstCol
      If col.EstImage Then
          col.Liste = GetType(List(Of Eleve)).GetProperty(col.SQLName).GetValue(Ret.LstDatas.LstObj, Nothing) 
      End If
  Next
```

I use it (vb.net), but I've

> La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet

I think it's because I've some null value or I take a wrong way?
It's the follow of [filter and sorter dynamic null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720165/expression-lambda-to-order-fields-with-null-value)

My eleve Stucture

```
Public Class Eleve

<TableFullOption.TFOAttribute("Key")> Property Id As Integer
<TableFullOption.TFOAttribute("Image")> Property Img As String
Property Name As String
Property Major As Boolean
<TableFullOption.TFOAttribute("FK_Sexe")> Property Sex As Integer
Property English As Nullable(Of Integer)
Property Japanese As Nullable(Of Double)
Property Calculus As Decimal
Property Geometry As Integer
End Class
```

and col.SQLName= "Img"

Can you help me...
I want to make a list of all image I've (mypicture.jpg, img1.png ...)

Comment: Which language is this? I can interpret it as `Object Reference error` is it?

Comment: the code is in vb.net

Comment: Not the code, I mean exception message.

Comment: It's in French. Sorry the translation : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You're asking for a property of the `List(Of Eleve)` type. That won't be an individual column name. It's not at all clear what your values are here, or what you're really trying to do, I'm afraid...

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I work on dynamic object with dynamic field. And I've several value, I check Ret.LstDatas.LstObj.  I create a big code to filter and sort all list of object. I work on image field (MyPicture.jpg ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `GetProperty()` statement returns `Nothing` because the property name is not found on type `List(T)`.

```
GetType(List(Of Eleve)).GetProperty(col.SQLName) = Nothing ' true
```

The exception is raised in the next call to `GetValue()`, because you are essentially calling a method on a null reference.

```
Nothing.GetValue(...)
```

---

Did you intend to find a property on type `Eleve` instead?

```
GetType(Eleve).GetProperty(col.SQLName)
```

Comment: You write... But when I tried that before ask help, I've error cause I search on list of Eleve : GetValue(Ret.LstDatas.LstObj, Nothing) I've message : The object does not match the target type

Answer (score 0):

I find ...
First I create a smart function

```
 Public Shared Function GetColumn(Of MaClass As Class)(ByVal items As List(Of MaClass), ByVal columnName As String) As List(Of String)
    Return items.Select(Function(x) If(x.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(x, Nothing), String.Empty).ToString).ToList
End Function
```

And I call like

```
 For Each col In Ret.StructTbl.LstCol
     If col.EstImage Then
         col.Liste = GetColumn(Of Eleve)(Ret.LstDatas.LstObj, col.SQLName)
     End If
 Next
```